# Write Excel with Pandas (different sheets and rows)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, for-loop, export-to-excel

I need to write to a `csv` some returns of a currency after 2 events take place (basically if the price column is above or below some other calculations).
The problem is I have 2 possible outcomes, for Buys and Sells (each should be in a different sheet in excel), and after the 2 events happened, I want to know the returns for the next 20 days. So each "event" (the conditions are true), should be added in a row, and the returns of the 20 days after the "event" happen each in a column.

So for example if I have 30 events in the buy part and 30 events in the sell part, I should have 2 sheets in the excel file and each with the following headers "event #" and 1,2,3,4...20.

The file will have 31 rows (header + the 30 events) and 21 columns (`Event` + 20 daily returns).

I have written the code for all of the program except the part in which I write the results to the excel file. Hope someone can help me. I've excluded reading the input files because I know how to do it. I also know how to write to a `csv`, but in my case is a little more complex and need help. Here is the  code so far, thank you.

The output example should look like this [Output Example Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z7hhE.png), the sell sheet it's the same.

Example Output Data:

```
   Events 1_day_after 2_day_after 3_day_after 4_day_after
0       1         XXX         XXX         XXX         XXX
1       2         XXX         XXX         XXX         XXX
2       3         XXX         XXX         XXX         XXX
3       4         XXX         XXX         XXX         XXX
4       5         XXX         XXX         XXX         XXX
```

```html
count_first_event = 0
buy=0
results_buy = []

for x in range(2711): 
     #is the first condition meet? 
     if df.iloc[x,3]>df.iloc[x,5] and df.iloc[x+1,3]<df.iloc[x+1,5]:
         count_first_event=count_first_event+1

         class BreakIt(Exception): pass
         try:    
             for y in range(20):
                 #is the second condition meet?
                 if df.iloc[x+y+1,3] <= df.iloc[x+y+1,6]:
                     buy=buy+1
                     
                     for z in range(20): 
                         #If we are here, just run the 20 times and then come back to the first FOR loop please!                    
                         results_buy.append(df.iloc[x+y+z+2,9])
                         if z==19:
                             raise BreakIt    
         except BreakIt:   
             pass     

print (results_buy)
```

Comment: While the code is appreciated, could you also supply some sample data? And what you want it to look like after? Might be able to do away with all the for-loops using just `pandas`

Comment: Thanks for your response. I understand it's a little complex, I added a image of what the result excel should look like. The XXX should be the values and the "sell" sheet should look as the "buy" sheet.

Comment: Could you also supply some starting sample data? Kinda hard to match the output without anything to start with. Also, try to post code-formatted data rather than pictures. Pictures can't be copied and ran through code.